# How do you pass a value from one function to another in same Lightning controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have the controller code as below

```
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getOpportunity");
    var quoId = component.get("v.recordId");
    action.setParams({ 
    "quoteId": quoId
    }); 
    action.setCallback(this, function(result) {
    var records = result.getReturnValue();
    if(records.length==0){
            component.set("v.showOppty",false);
            component.set("v.strErrorMsg",'This account does not have any related dealerships. Please cancel and select another account.');
            component.set("v.errorMsg",true);
       }
        else{
            component.set("v.showOppty",true);
            component.set("v.Opportunity",records[0]);
            //alert(component.find("a_opt"));
            component.find("a_opt").set("v.value", "Identify/Define");
            component.set("v.RoofTopRec.Deal_Type__c",records[0].Deal_Type__c);

        }


          // component.set("v.selectedOpportunity",records.Name); 
            //alert(records.length);



    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

I have second function in the same controller as below

```
goToRoofTop: function(component, event, helper) {

    component.set("v.showOppty",false);
    var action = component.get("c.SaveRoofTop");

    action.setParams({ 
        "oppty": component.get("v.Opportunity"),
        "rfTop": component.get("v.RoofTopRec")

    }); 
    action.setCallback(this, function(result) {
        var records = result.getReturnValue();
        component.set("v.RecId",records);
        component.set("v.showRooftops",true);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

I want to pass "quoteId" from the doinit function, which is the record id to the "SaveRoofTop" function. The apex controller is as below

```
@AuraEnabled
public static string SaveRoofTop(Opportunity oppty,Rooftop_Engagement_Details__c rfTop, Quote qte){

    system.debug('qte>>>>>===='+oppty);
    rfTop.Parent_Opportunity__c =oppty.id;
    //rfTop.Quote__c =quoteId.id;

    rfTop.Dealer_Group_Account__c = oppty.AccountId;
    insert rfTop; 

    system.debug('rfTop=='+rfTop.id);
    return rfTop.id;   

}
```

The component is as below

```
<aura:attribute name="Quote" type="Quote"  default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Quote'}"/>
<aura:attribute name="Opportunity" type="Opportunity"  default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Opportunity'}"/>
<aura:attribute name="RoofTopRec" type="Rooftop_Engagement_Details__c" 
           default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Rooftop_Engagement_Details__c'}"/>


<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.errorMsg}">
        <ui:message title="Error" severity="error" closable="true">
            {!v.strErrorMsg}
        </ui:message>
</aura:if> 

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.showOppty}">

    <div class="container slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--2-of-2 slds-medium-size--5-of-6 slds-large-size--12-of-12">

        <ui:inputText aura:id="idDealType" label="Deal Type" class="slds-input" labelClass="slds-form-element__label"                                      value="{!v.RoofTopRec.Deal_Type__c}" disabled="true"/>
        <ui:inputText aura:id="idAccount" label="Dealer group Account" class="slds-input" labelClass="slds-form-element__label" value="{!v.Opportunity.Account.Name}" disabled="true"/>
        <ui:inputText aura:id="idOppty" label="Parent Opportunity" class="slds-input" labelClass="slds-form-element__label" value="{!v.Opportunity.Name}" disabled="true"/>

   </div>
   <div class="slds-card__footer slds-p-vertical--large">
       <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save and continue" onclick="{!c.goToRoofTop}" />
   </div>

</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.showRooftops}">

  <c:RoofTopComponent aura:id="child" recordId="{!v.RecId}"/>
  </aura:if>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77014/discussion-between-psh-and-jayant-das).

Answer (score 2):

You would either move this functionality to the helper class where you have access to `this` ie call like this:

```
//[controller]
function : doSomething(component,event,helper){
    helper.doSomething(component);
    ...
}

//[helper]
function : doSomething(component){
    this.doSomethingElse(component);
},
function : doSomethingElse(component){
}
```

Or you can declare a method at the top level that has an action in the controller class.

ie:

```
//component def
<aura:method name="doSomethingElseOnTheController" action="{!c.doSomethingElseOnTheController}"/>

//[controller]
function : doSomething(component,event,helper){
    component.doSomethingElseOnTheController(component);
    ...
},
function : doSomethingElseOnTheController(component,event,helper){
    ...etc
},
```

Then in the controller just call it like this:

```
component.dosomethingonthecontroller();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But could you please explain more. I am sorry , I am bit new to lightning component development

Comment: Added some more details

Comment: So the apex controller method "SaveRoofTop" has three params. I am able to send them two params and its getting the ID. But the last param i.e Quote qte, is getting null even if I pass the record id. In the doinit, the recordId is working fine. But the second function is after I click a button and there the recordId is null

Comment: Your code is kind of a mess. I'm not going to fix it sorry.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATES:**

You have quite a few things going wrong here.

1. You don't seem to have the *recordId* defined anywhere in the component (at least I can't see that). I am not sure how you are getting this in your *doInit* function 
   `var quoId = component.get("v.recordId");`
2. I am not sure how's your definition of *recordId* looks like, but you should try setting the *quoId* that you retrieve in *doInit* in another aura:attribute on the component. Then use that attribute in *gotToRoofTop* function.
3. Additionally what you are trying to pass from JS to Apex, you won't be do it that way. Refer to this SFSE [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216770/error-when-trying-to-extract-listaccount-information-from-map/216780?noredirect=1#comment328357_216780), on how to pass complex data types from JS to Apex
4. Your code in the post does not really look to be complete in all sense. It has lots of missing pieces. E.g., the component is not complete, the doInit apex action is not there, similarly the class is incomplete too. While I cannot completely help you fixing all of your code, but try to put console logs and debug statements all across the flow to identify the source of the problem. Keep the bare minimum content to be able to identify it fast. Search for the error messages that you get. This forum is full of examples around troubleshooting lightning issues, so you will get lot of information around it.
5. Finally go through some learning on lightning. A good starting point would be trailhead.

If you can pin point to exact problem, happy to help from there.

---

What you need here is to access a value in your `goToRoofTop` JS function on click of a button. For this you don’t really need to pass it from your `doInit` function. The issue based on your code snippet that you were trying to use, which was as below.

You used `component.get("v.recordId")` in ***doInit*** whereas you were trying to use `component.get("v.recordid")` in your ***gotoRoofToop*** JS. The issue is in your lower case ***i***. It should be same as what you had in your init function:`component.get("v.recordId")`.

Comment: I corrected the lowercase "I" as you had suggested and still got the same error.

Comment: This is how it is now
action.setParams({ 
            "oppty": component.get("v.Opportunity"),
            "rfTop": component.get("v.RoofTopRec"),
            "qte":component.get("v.recordId")

Answer (score 0):

This was purely my mistake of passing the wrong params to the apex controller. I was passing the recordId for the method, that was expecting an sObject. Modifed controller is as below.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static string SaveRoofTop( Opportunity oppty,Rooftop_Engagement_Details__c rfTop, id qte){

    system.debug('qte>>>>>===='+qte);
    rfTop.Parent_Opportunity__c =oppty.id;
    rfTop.Quote__c =qte;

    rfTop.Dealer_Group_Account__c = oppty.AccountId;
    insert rfTop; 

    system.debug('rfTop=='+rfTop.id);
    return rfTop.id;   

}
```