# Pass parameter from lightning component to controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I try to pass date value to controller parameter and use it as a query but end up with error "attempt to de-reference a null object". Is there something that i missed?

I got an "ERROR" state when execute the method.

[image]

**Note there are records that match with my query**

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="BACSPaymentManagerController">
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
    <aura:attribute name="BACSPaymentDatetime" type="Datetime" />
    <aura:attribute name="DateDueStart" type="Date"/>
    <aura:attribute name="DateDueEnd" type="Date" />
    <aura:attribute name="NextNDays" type="Integer" />
    <aura:attribute name="BACSConfirmation" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="BACSConfirmationAnswer" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Notification" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="paymentRecords" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="selectedRows" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="rowsSelected" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List" />   
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.init}" value="{!this}" />
    <aura:handler event="aura:waiting" action="{!c.waiting}"/>
    <aura:handler event="aura:doneWaiting" action="{!c.doneWaiting}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="wait" type="String"/>

    <lightning:card title="BACS" iconName="standard:file">
        <!-- INPUT GRID -->
        <div class="slds-grid_vertical slds-gutters">
            <div class="slds-col slds-grid ">
                <div class="slds-col slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <span>Please select payments with due<br/>dates between the following dates</span>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-grid_vertical">
                    <div class="slds-col">
                        <lightning:input type="date" label="Date Due Start" value="{!v.DateDueStart}" required="true"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col">
                        <lightning:input type="date" label="Date Due End" value="{!v.DateDueEnd}" required="true"/>
                    </div>
                    <!--<div class="slds-col">
                        <lightning:input type="Number" label="Next N Days" value="{!v.NextNDays}" required="true"/>
                    </div>-->
                </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <lightning:button class="slds-button_brand" label="Fetch Payments" onclick="{!c.fetchPayments}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

**Client side Controller**

```
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) {
        var today = new Date();
        var monthDigit = today.getMonth() + 1;
        if (monthDigit <= 9) {
            monthDigit = '0' + monthDigit;
        }
        component.set("v.DateDueStart", today.getFullYear() + "-" + monthDigit + "-" + today.getDate());
    },

    fetchPayments : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.fetchPayments(component, event);
    }
}
```

**Helper**

```
({
    fetchPayments : function(component, event) {
        var startDate = component.get("v.DateDueStart");
        var endDate = component.get("v.DateDueEnd");
        console.log(startDate + ' --'+endDate);
        var action = component.get("c.getPayments");
        action.setParams({"DateDueStart":component.get("v.DateDueStart"), "DateDueEnd":component.get("v.DateDueEnd")});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            console.log(response.getState());
            if(response.getState() == 'SUCCESS'){
                if(response.getReturnValue() != undefined){
                    component.set("v.columns",[
                        {label:'Id', fieldName:'Id',type:'text'},
                        {label:'Payment Id', fieldName:'Name',type:'text'},
                        {label:'Client Reference', fieldName:'Contact__r.Client_Reference__c',type:'text'},
                        {label:'Client Status', fieldName:'Contact__r.Status__c',type:'text'},
                        {label:'Amount', fieldName:'Amount_Paid__c', type:'currency', typeAttribute:{currencyCode:'GBP'}},
                        {label:'Payment Code', fieldName:'Payment_Code__r.Name',type:'text'},
                        {label:'Payment Type', fieldName:'Payment_Type__c',type:'text'},
                        {label:'Date Due', fieldName:'Date_Due__c',type:'date'},
                        {label:'Date Paid', fieldName:'Date_Paid__c',type:'date'}
                    ]);
                    component.set("v.paymentRecords", response.getReturnValue());
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class BACSPaymentManagerController {
        @AuraEnabled
        public static List<Payment__c> getPayments(Date DateDueStart, Date DateDueEnd){
            Date startDate = Date.newInstance(DateDueStart.year(),DateDueStart.month(),DateDueStart.day());
            Date endDate = Date.newInstance(DateDueEnd.year(),DateDueEnd.month(),DateDueEnd.day());
            if(DateDueStart != null && DateDueEnd != null){
                List<Payment__c> allFilteredPayments = [SELECT Date_Paid__c, Amount_Paid__c, Name, Name__c, Account_Number__c, Sort_Code__c, Contact__r.Client_Reference__c, Contact__r.Status__c, Contact__r.Client_Reference_BACS__c, Date_Due__c, Payment_Code__r.Name, Payment_Type__c FROM Payment__c WHERE Payment_Type__c = 'BACS' AND Date_Paid__c =NULL AND Confirm_Payment__c = false AND Date_Due__c >= :startDate AND Date_Due__c <=:endDate];
                return allFilteredPayments;      
            }
            else{
                List<Payment__c> allFilteredPayments = [SELECT Date_Paid__c, Amount_Paid__c, Name, Name__c, Account_Number__c, Sort_Code__c, Contact__r.Client_Reference__c, Contact__r.Status__c, Contact__r.Client_Reference_BACS__c, Date_Due__c, Payment_Code__r.Name, Payment_Type__c FROM Payment__c WHERE Payment_Type__c = 'BACS' AND Date_Paid__c =NULL AND Confirm_Payment__c = false];
                return allFilteredPayments;      
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please check your date value in server side. Use system.debug log I think you are getting null values. I think you are getting error in else part of your code

Comment: Are you getting proper dates in controller method?

Comment: @AnnappaPH i have use system.debug log on controller side but it didnt show in logs, i get the date value in client side controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer by myself. I change my apex controller parameter type from Date to String then change that string to date using `Date.valueof(stringDate)`.

Here is the complete code

**client-side controller**

```
fetchPayments : function(component, event) {
        var startDate = component.get("v.DateDueStart");
        var endDate = component.get("v.DateDueEnd");
        var action = component.get("c.getPayments");
        action.setParams({"DateDueStart":startDate, "DateDueEnd":endDate});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            console.log(response.getState());
            if(response.getState() == 'SUCCESS'){
                if(response.getReturnValue() != undefined){
                    component.set("v.columns",[
                        {label:'Id', fieldName:'Id',type:'text'},
                        {label:'Payment Id', fieldName:'Name',type:'text'},
                        {label:'Client Reference', fieldName:'Contact__r.Client_Reference__c',type:'text'},
                        {label:'Client Status', fieldName:'Contact__r.Status__c',type:'text'},
                        {label:'Amount', fieldName:'Amount_Paid__c', type:'currency', typeAttribute:{currencyCode:'GBP'}},
                        {label:'Payment Code', fieldName:'Payment_Code__r.Name',type:'text'},
                        {label:'Payment Type', fieldName:'Payment_Type__c',type:'text'},
                        {label:'Date Due', fieldName:'Date_Due__c',type:'date'},
                        {label:'Date Paid', fieldName:'Date_Paid__c',type:'date'}
                    ]);
                    component.set("v.paymentRecords", response.getReturnValue());
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

**server-side controller**

```
public static List<Payment__c> getPayments(String DateDueStart, String DateDueEnd){
        Date startDate = Date.valueOf(DateDueStart);
        Date endDate = Date.valueOf(DateDueEnd);

        if(DateDueStart != null && DateDueEnd != null){
            List<Payment__c> allFilteredPayments = [SELECT Date_Paid__c, Amount_Paid__c, Name, Name__c, Account_Number__c, Sort_Code__c, Contact__r.Client_Reference__c, Contact__r.Status__c, Contact__r.Client_Reference_BACS__c, Date_Due__c, Payment_Code__r.Name, Payment_Type__c FROM Payment__c WHERE Payment_Type__c = 'BACS' AND Date_Paid__c =NULL AND Confirm_Payment__c = false AND Date_Due__c >= :startDate AND Date_Due__c <=:endDate];
            return allFilteredPayments;      
        }
        else{
            List<Payment__c> allFilteredPayments = [SELECT Date_Paid__c, Amount_Paid__c, Name, Name__c, Account_Number__c, Sort_Code__c, Contact__r.Client_Reference__c, Contact__r.Status__c, Contact__r.Client_Reference_BACS__c, Date_Due__c, Payment_Code__r.Name, Payment_Type__c FROM Payment__c WHERE Payment_Type__c = 'BACS' AND Date_Paid__c =NULL AND Confirm_Payment__c = false];
            return allFilteredPayments;      
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic problem of passing complex data types other than String to Apex controllers from JS. You can refer to such of one posts [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216770/error-when-trying-to-extract-listaccount-information-from-map/216780#216780).

In your case, even though you get the right values in your JS, when it reaches to your apex method, it never reaches as a valid *Date* instead as a **null**. And you can verify this by putting a debug statement to print it in your apex method.

Then when you try to retrieve the values on the line `Date startDate = Date.newInstance(DateDueStart.year(),DateDueStart.month(),DateDueStart.day());` and because the `DateDueStart` was always **null**, you get the NPE.

One of the approaches (that I have always used to overcome such issues) is that you would need to **stringify** the date value from your JS controller and then accordingly change that back to a date in your apex method.

So your JS code where you are setting the parameters for apex method becomes as:

```
action.setParams({"DateDueStart":JSON.stringify(component.get("v.DateDueStart")), "DateDueEnd":JSON.stringify(component.get("v.DateDueEnd"))});
```

And then in your apex method becomes as:

```
 @AuraEnabled
 public static List<Payment__c> getPayments(String DateDueStart, String DateDueEnd) {
    DateTime startDate = (DateTime) JSON.deserialize(DateDueStart, DateTime.class);
    ....rest of the code....
}
```

---

An additional note, change your logic where you compare the dates for null in your apex.

**From**: `if(DateDueStart != null && DateDueEnd != null)`

**To**: `if(startDate != null && endDate != null)`

And this is because you are using these variables in your SOQL and not the ones you received as an argument in your method.