# Can't we iterate the wrapperclass list in in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am getting the error while i am iterating the wrapper list in aura method. It is throwing exception System.unexpected exception.`I am getting the error while i am iterating the wrapper list in aura method. It is throwing exception System.unexpected exception.

Apex: CLass

```
@AuraEnabled
Public static List<wrapperClass> searchForDuplicates(List<wrapperClass> wrapperList){
    Set<String> searchset = new Set<String>();
    List<wrapperClass> dupList = new List<wrapperClass>();
    for(wrapperClass wc :wrapperList){
        if(wc.isSelected == true){
             System.debug('Test3'+wrapperList);
            searchset.add(wc.a.BillingCity +'#');
            searchset.add(wc.a.BillingPostalCode +'#');
            searchset.add(wc.a.BillingCountry +'#');
            searchset.add(wc.a.BillingState +'#');
            searchset.add(wc.a.BillingStreet +'#');
        }
    }
   for (wrapperClass w : wrapperList){
        if(w.isSelected == true && !searchset.contains(w.a.BillingCity) && !searchset.contains(w.a.BillingPostalCode) && !searchset.contains(w.a.BillingCountry) &&
           !searchset.contains(w.a.BillingState) && !searchset.contains(w.a.BillingStreet)){
               dupList.add(w);
          }
    }

    return wrapperList;      
}`
```

Javascript Controller:

```
onRowSelect: function (component, event, helper) {

var action = component.get("c.searchForDuplicates");
action.setParams({
    wrapperList: component.get("v.currentList")
});
alert(JSON.stringify(component.get("v.currentList")));
action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
    var state = response.getState();

    if (state == "SUCCESS") {
        var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");

        evt.setParams({
            componentDef: "c:TestDup",
            componentAttributes: {
                duplicatesInAcc: response.getReturnValue()
            }
        });
        evt.fire();

    } else {
        var errors = response.getError();
        alert('errors==' + JSON.stringify(errors));
        if (errors) {
            if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                console.log("Error message: " + errors[0].message);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Unknown error");
        }
    }

});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Comment: System.unexpected exception

Comment: any extra string or detail? Line number? something more verbose?

Comment: FATAL_ERROR System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System Error: 1848583798-31248 (856768494) (856768494)

Comment: Can you add a null check to see wrapperList is not null in APex? and also can you debug wrapperList to see if there is a value in it?

Comment: To me it seems you will need to *stringify* the list while setting it in the JS controller and then *deserialize* it in your aura method. You may like to take a look at a similar issue [**here**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216770/error-when-trying-to-extract-listaccount-information-from-map/216780#216780) which was resolved using this approach.

Comment: I apologize for saying this but if the above code is complete, it makes no sense to me. You are passing `wrapperlist` to `searchForDuplicates` and then returning it back again without any transformation. Are you supposed to return `duplist` or `wrapperlist`?